# PrivateRoute on React is not redirecting when loggedIn user is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement some security into my app and ended up creating this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  auth: { isAuthenticated, loading },
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (
        <Redirect to='/auth/login' />
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

`auth` comes from my state management that looks exactly like this when viewed from the Redux Devtools installed on my Chrome browser; here it is:

[image: redux devtools console]

`isAuthenticated` and `loading` are usually true when a user is loggedIn; that works just fine. The problem I'm having is that my PrivateRoute does not redirect to the `auth/login` page when no one is loggedIn. Does anyone has any idea on how to fix this?. This is an example of one of my routes that need the PrivateRoute component:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/edit-basics' component={EditBasics} />
```

The route above is a page to edit the current loggedIn user info only available to him/her. I'm still accessing to it without being loggedIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're probably getting errors from having the `&&` operator and two expressions inside of the ternary operation that you're passing to the `render` method of `Route`.

You'll have to find a different way to validate if it's still loading.

In JSX if you pair `true && expression` it evaluates to `expression` – so basically you're returning `!loading` as a component to render.

Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  auth: { isAuthenticated, loading },
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>

      // TWO OPERATIONS WITH && WILL CAUSE ERROR
      !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (

        <Redirect to='/auth/login' />
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Also,

React Router's authors recommend constructing this kind of private route with child components instead of passing the component to render as a prop.

Read more: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

```
function PrivateRoute({ auth, children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() =>
        !auth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/auth/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          children
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

And to call that route:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/protected" auth={auth} >
   <ProtectedPage customProp="some-prop" />
</PrivateRoute>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing down the auth prop to the PrivateRoute. Try adding it.

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/edit-basics' component={EditBasics} auth={this.props.auth}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component,
 auth: { isAuthenticated, loading },
...options }) => {
  let history = useHistory();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if ( !isAuthenticated && !loading) history.push('/auth/login')
  }, [])

  return <Route {...options} component={component} />;
};
```